# Unable to communicate to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to S3 bucket, the upload happens successfully but after the upload it is giving me an exception saying

```
   Unable to communicate to S3
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException
    at com.amazonaws.internal.ResettableInputStream.newResettableInputStream(ResettableInputStream.java:302) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.166.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.ResettableInputStream.newResettableInputStream(ResettableInputStream.java:277) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.166.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.ReleasableInputStream.wrap(ReleasableInputStream.java:129) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.166.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadPartRequestFactory.<init>(UploadPartRequestFactory.java:68) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.166.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInParts(UploadCallable.java:184) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.166.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.call(UploadCallable.java:123) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.166.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:143) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.166.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:48) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.166.jar!/:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.ensureOpen(FileChannelImpl.java:109) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.position(FileChannelImpl.java:252) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.ResettableInputStream.<init>(ResettableInputStream.java:113) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.166.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.ResettableInputStream.<init>(ResettableInputStream.java:101) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.166.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.ResettableInputStream.newResettableInputStream(ResettableInputStream.java:300) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.166.jar!/:?]
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please Edit your question and show us your code. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: More information required to answer your question. Please add more information.